# What is the term for the product of two prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

Numbers that can be factored down into 2 and only 2 prime numbers, such as:

```
25 (5 * 5)
9 (3 * 3)
12752041 (3571 * 3571)
```

Is there a mathematical term for these numbers?  I did a bit of Googling, but it's tough to search for what something is *called*.

**Update:** To clarify, I meant the square of a single prime number.  So n * n where n is prime.

Comment: semiprime aaaaa

Comment: When I looked up semiprime, it says it's a product of two prime numbers, but those prime numbers are not necessarily distinct.  So 15 (3 * 5) could be semiprime, correct?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Frankly, I doubt it, cos' you can just call them *squares of prime numbers*.

Comment: Thanks!  Though @cassandra0's answer was helpful too.  I'm learning about cryptography, and semiprimes come up quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "prime power" is usually used to refer to numbers of the form $p^n$ with $p$ prime and $n \geq 1$. I imagine "prime squared" or "prime square" is the most reasonable name for what you're describing.